# Strunk & White? Moderators included? Questions only? Answers only?

Tags: support, badges

According to the new [Users page which now shows edits](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) I have 268 edits. If I am reading the [Strunk & White badge](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white) properly it should only take 80 edits to earn this badge but I haven't earned it yet and neither has Lèse majesté. Are mods allowed to earn this badge? Is it only on Question edits? Or answer edits?

**UPDATE**

I just got the Strunk & White badge today. The [User's Editors page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) shows me as having 440 edits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edits that only affect the tags, or edits that are to your own questions do not count.  This could be cause for a discrepancy.  Edits to both questions and answers count.

Yes, everyone is able to receive the badge.  There are no badges that moderators are ineligible for.

All of the specific badge requirements can be found [in this Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Comment: That's a very handy link. Explains exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is broken, Lèse majesté also meets the min requirements of 80 edits. The Stack Exchange team did decrease the number of edits required for Strunk and White from 100 to 80 in Nov or Dec of 2010 so maybe there is a bug. I retagged your question with the [bug](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) as it looks like it isn't working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I also meet the minimum, but did not receive it. Hope it gets fixed. :)

Comment: Please double check the requirements - http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/431/strunk-white-moderators-included-questions-only-answers-only/467#467